# User input program not working," != "?

Tags: python

Just messing around with Python 3 functions and user inputs, but really scratching my head here as to why != won't work? If the user enters YES or yes it still produces the message "Invalid answer. YES or NO only!"?

Thanks

```
def program():
    valid_answers = ("YES", "yes", "NO", "no")
    variable_input = input("Are bananas yellow? Answer YES or NO: ")

    if variable_input != valid_answers:
        print("Invalid answer. YES or NO only!")
        program()

    elif variable_input == "YES":
        print("Correct! They are!")
        program()
    elif variable_input == "yes":
        print("Correct! They are!")
        program()
    elif variable_input == "NO":
        print("Try again. They are definitely yellow.")
        program()
    elif variable_input == "no":
        print("Try again. They are definitely yellow.")
        program()
program()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would make `valid_answers` a list. != means not equal or equivalent to. Instead of !=, you `not in`.You should write the code like this:

```
def program():
    valid_answers = ["YES", "yes", "NO", "no"] # Note the change from tuple to list
    variable_input = input("Are bananas yellow? Answer YES or NO: ")

    if variable_input not in valid_answers: # Note the != to not in
        # do something

    # rest of your code
```

Responding to the comment...

For the multiple options in `input`, you could use a tuple and "scan" it to see if `variable_input` exists in the tuple, and then follow an action like so:

```
elif variable_input == ("yes", "YES"):
    # do something
```

Now, if I remember correctly, in Python 3 you can also use the `or` operator instead of a tuple. :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Obviously very new to Python programming, finding my feet but thank you. Is there any way to condense: elif variable_input == "NO":
        print("Try again. They are definitely yellow.")
        program()
    elif variable_input == "no":
        print("Try again. They are definitely yellow.")

Comment: No Problem! Glad I could help! If you need anything else, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the `variable_input` literally does not equal the tuple. You want to check if `variable_input` is `not in` the tuple.

```
if variable_input != valid_answers:
```

Should be:

```
if variable_input not in valid_answers:
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to condense the code to something like: elif variable_input == "NO" or "no": print...

Answer (score 1):

**Correction:**

`if variable_input != valid_answers:` should be `if variable_input not in valid_answers:`

And you can reduce the if statement like this:

**Final program:**

```
def program():
    valid_answers = ("YES", "yes", "NO", "no")
    variable_input = input("Are bananas yellow? Answer YES or NO: ")

    if variable_input not in valid_answers:
        print("Invalid answer. YES or NO only!")
        program()
    elif variable_input in ["YES", "yes"]: 
        print("Correct! They are!")
        program()
    elif variable_input in ["NO", "no"]:
        print("Try again. They are definitely yellow.")
        program()

program()
```